# Taghelper: Cannot resolve TagHelper containing assembly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, tag-helpers

I cannot get a custom TagHelper to work in my ASP.NET v5 project. The custom TagHelper is located in the web project itself. I tried following this sample [this sample](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/986917/Introducing-TagHelpers-with-ASP-NET-on-EverLeap) from CodeProject and [this tutorial](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/275/custom-taghelpers-in-asp-net-mvc-6) too.

When I try to use the tag without `addTagHelper`:
nothing is transformed, no breakpoints hit in the tag helper.

When I try to `@addTagHelper "*, MyWebApplication"` to the Viewcomponent, the error is `MyWebApplication'. Error: Could not load file or assembly 'MyWebApplication'`.

What am I missing?

Tool versions:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 RC
Version 14.0.22823.1 D14REL
Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.6.00057
Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc 6.0.0-beta4
```

Comment: Can you add the helper to another assembly, and see if that resolves the issue?

Comment: That was my next step but I worked it out - see my answer

Comment: See Authoring   taghelpers http://bit.ly/1Mqd0th  which explains this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The advertised signature for addTagHelper is

`@addTagHelper "className/Filter", "assemblyName"`

Behaviour actually appears to be (at least for helpers in same web project)

`addTagHelper "className/Filter", "folderName"`

because at least into Beta6, the assembly name is the folder name and ignores the attributes in the project properties.

Here is a [sample working demo](https://github.com/neutmute/aspnetv5demo)

1. Hit F5, view cats.
2. Edit the project properties to change the assembly name.
3. Hit F5, view cats. << *This should not work?!*
4. Close solution, rename the on disk directory `TagHelperDemo` -> 
   `TagHelperFolderDemo`
5. Observe page fails until the folder name is used for `addTagHelper` directive

PS: `@addTagHelper` is required even when the `TagHelper` is in the same project. VS2015 re-colours the tag as purple when it is targeted by a `TagHelper`.

Comment: It's still the issue in Core 1.1. You need to specify folder, not assembly. For example, if project is in "proj-name/src/proj-name.csproj", then correct directive is @addTagHelper "*, proj-name" regardless of your namespace.